# web.config transforms not working for log4net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following

`<log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="D:\projects\Code\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>`

for the release i would like to change the file path, but it doesnt seem to work, here is what i have in my web.release.config

`<log4net xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" >
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="c:\temp.txt" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(value)" />

    </appender> 
  </log4net>`

here is the result

`<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="D:\projects\Code\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>`

Its removing the debug part as it should but its not fixing the file path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this.

```
`<log4net>
    <appender name="InfoRollingLogFileAppender"   type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{ProgramDataPath}\errorLog" />
```

...

    
  `

When you initialize the logger, then

```
var path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogLocation"];
        // Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);
        GlobalContext.Properties["ProgramDataPath"] = path;
        XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Logger));
```

Finally just change the value in LogLocation.
I hope this could help you. Thanks